# Read UTF-8 XML with MSXML 4.0

Tags: asp-classic, utf-8, character-encoding, msxml

I have a problem with classc ASP / VBScript trying to read an UTF-8 encoded XML file with MSXML. The file is encoded correctly, I can see that with all other tools.

Constructed XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<itshop>
    <Product Name="Backup gewünscht" />
</itshop>
```

If I try to do this in ASP...

```
Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("input.xml", FOR_READING)
XML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
Set ts = nothing
Set fso = Nothing

Set myXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
myXML.loadXML(XML)
Set DocElement = myXML.documentElement
Set ProductNodes = DocElement.selectNodes("//Product")
Response.Write ProductNodes(0).getAttribute("Name")
' ...
```

... and Name contains special characters (german umlauts to be specific) the bytes of the umlaut "two-byte-code" get reencoded, so I end up with two totally crappy nonsense characters. What should be "ü" becomes "Ã¼" - being FOUR bytes in my output, not two (correct UTF-8) or one (ISO-8859-#).

What am I doing wrong? Why is MSXML thinking that the input is ISO-8859-# so that it tries to convert it to UTF-8?

Comment: The uppercase VB statements make my eyes hurt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("input.xml", FOR_READING, False, True)
```

The last parameter is the "Unicode" flag.

OpenTextFile() has the following signature:

```
object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
```

where "format" is defined as

> Optional. One of three Tristate values used to indicate the format of
>   the opened file. If omitted, the file
>   is opened as ASCII.

And Tristate is defined as:

```
TristateUseDefault  -2   Opens the file using the system default.
TristateTrue        -1   Opens the file as Unicode.
TristateFalse        0   Opens the file as ASCII.
```

And -1 happens to be the numerical value of `True`.

Anyway, better is:

```
Set myXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
myXML.load("input.xml")
```

Why should you use a `TextStream` object to read in a file that MSXML can read perfectly on it's own.

The `TextStream` object also has no notion of the *actual* file encoding. The docs say "Unicode", but there is more than one way of encoding Unicode. The `load()` method of the MSXML object will be able to deal with all of them.

Comment: Try the "myXML.load()" variant. If that fails as well, the file is not well formed.

Comment: Great, that works. I had the loadXML version because there is another way of submitting the XML (which is by inserting the XML code into a form field). Guess I will just disable that option. Nobody will need that anyway if there is an upload function :)

Comment: You can also just wrap that in an If .. Then ... Else. :-)

Comment: (I already put that in an If...Then...Else, but it still breaks character encoding if I use "loadXML")

Comment: Forget everything I said. load works, loadXML works. I just believed the bug report I got without trying myself.

Comment: Confirmed: Everything works as expected now. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: myXML.load("input.xml") is sort of silly, the parentheses don't belong there.  This sort of thing is a bad habit and will burn you elsewhere.  The FSO can only handle ASCII and "Unicode" (i.e. UTF-16LE).  When you want to read/write alternate text encodings or binary data consider using ADODB.Stream instead.  It is handy and quite versatile.  Clearly not required at all in this case though.